# SQL Strategy for Millions of Records & Multiple Categories for Each

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database of over 1.3 million records. Each one of these records has one or more categories (or tags) associated with it by using a category match table that holds one or more rows matching the placeid with a catid.  I am using a full text search to find matches in the placename and/or fullloc (full location) field.

As you will see in the query below, I am using an "inner join" and "group by" to handle the matching of categories. There are close to 40 categories that a place may be associated with.  When searching 1.3 million records this is VERY slow.

```
SELECT 
  MATCH(placename,fullloc) AGAINST ('chappaqua school' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    as score, 
  places.PlaceName, places.fullloc, places.PlaceID, places.ImageThumb, 
  places.contributorid, places.verified, places.verified_by, 
  places.verified_date, places.visibility 
FROM places 
WHERE STATUS IN (1,0) 
  AND MATCH(placename,fullloc) AGAINST ('chappaqua school' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
  AND places_cats.CATID IN (129,75,104,126,115,140,128,137,136,114,135,
    105,142,141,90,121,122,117,98,1,130,127,25,116,102,5,
    88,87,31,24,37,134,39,40,112,34,30,133,9,8,7,11,20,19,
    3,2,4,131,132,89,38,125,139,36,124,138,35,119,118,120,
    96,97,95,13,17,14,12,21,15,32,16,26,29,28,27,85,86,84) 
  AND (visibility = 1 ) 
GROUP BY PlaceID 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 500
```

I am looking for some help finding a new way to handle the Categories.  Is there a way to do it by storing the CatIDs in the Places table?

Here is the EXPLAIN for the above query....

```
1,SIMPLE,places,fulltext,"PRIMARY,by_plaeid,by_full_text",by_full_text,0,,1,Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1,SIMPLE,places_cats,ref,"by_PlaceIDandCatID,by_catid,by_catID_and_placeID,by_placeid",by_placeid,4,mapthepast.places.PlaceID,1,Using where
```

The above query currently takes 10.8 seconds.  Removing the Category JOIN (below), the execution time drops to 2.08.

```
SELECT MATCH(placename,fullloc) AGAINST ('chappaqua school' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score, 
places.PlaceName, places.fullloc, places.PlaceID, places.ImageThumb, places.contributorid, places.verified, places.verified_by, places.verified_date, places.visibility 
FROM places 
WHERE STATUS IN (1,0) AND MATCH(placename,fullloc) AGAINST ('chappaqua school' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
GROUP BY PlaceID 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 500
```

Comment: 1.3 million  rows in not very many. Do you have appropriate indexes?

Comment: Can you give us the explain for that query?

Comment: What is the difference in query execution time with/without the places_cats.CATID in the WHERE clause? The EXPLAIN output (as mentioned in a previous comment) would be useful to understand the costs of this query.

Comment: Here is the EXPLAIN for the above query.........1,SIMPLE,places,fulltext,"PRIMARY,by_plaeid,by_full_text",by_full_text,0,,1,Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1,SIMPLE,places_cats,ref,"by_PlaceIDandCatID,by_catid,by_catID_and_placeID,by_placeid",by_placeid,4,mapthepast.places.PlaceID,1,Using where

Comment: While using `IN` with a subquery can be slow, a static list like that should be fast enough. It looks like MySQL is prefering to use the index for place_id, despite you having what looks like a composite for place_id and cat_id. Try an `USE INDEX` statement to explicit ask MySQL to use the composite index.